# Оптимизация вычисления интегральной матрицы

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

У меня есть одноканальная матрица размерности width x height. Мне необходимо вычислить на ее основе интегральную матрицу, где каждый ее элемент на позиции [x, y] будет равен сумме всех элементов изначальной матрицы в прямоугольнике [0, 0, x, y]. Простейший алгоритм. Как его ускорить? Очевидный вариант: разбить вычисление на два этапа — сначала вычисляем суммы по горизонтали и записываем в выходную матрицу, а потом вычисляем суммы по вертикали на основе предыдущего шага. Каждую горизонталь и вертикаль обрабатываем в отдельном потоке и в результате все должно происходить очень быстро. Однако когда я заимплементил это на `cuda` (два ядра: одно для горизонтали, второе для вертикали) и сравнил результат с `cv::integral`, то был неприятно удивлен - `cv::integral` работало в 4-5 раз быстрее, чем вычисления на `cuda` (я засекал именно вычисления, копирование с `cpu` на `gpu` и обратно не производилось)! Значит, в `opencv` используется какой-то гораздо более продвинутый алгоритм. Какие еще есть варианты оптимизации вычисления интегральной матрицы?

Comment: Однопоточный алгоритм линейный по числу элементов, тут больше ловить нечего. Микрооптимизации, тонкая работа с памятью, видимо. Однако некоторое время назад была ветка про многопоточное вычисление кумулятивной суммы в массиве - и там есть хитрости, которые могут ускорить процесс. Ключевых слов не помню.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum

Comment: Если горизонталь 2000 элементов, то её можно на несколько потоков разбить.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков можно конкретнее? Вы имеете ввиду то, что можно разбить вычисление по горизонтали на несколько потоков?

Comment: Да. Насколко это поможет не могу сказать.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков и как же это будет работать? Можете рассказать как это разбить на несколько потоков?

Comment: Что мешает открыть исходники OpenCV  и разобраться?

Comment: @AlexAlex наверное потому что вопрос не в том, как это реализовано в opencv, а в том как оптимизировать алгоритм на cuda